# WPF modal borderless window effect when click on parent window

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a custom borderless window:

```
<Window x:Class="MyBorderlessWindow"
    ...
    WindowStyle="None"
    ShowInTaskbar="False" 
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
    ResizeMode="NoResize"
    AllowsTransparency="True">
```

And I set the owner of my borderless window to a parent window, in order to make it modal:

```
// in a parent window
var myWindow = new MyBorderlessWindow();
myWindow.Owner = this;
myWindow.ShowDialog();
```

But when I switch apps and back, and click on the parent window, window effects are different.

If the child window is a normal style window, the child will be brought back to the topmost.

However, my custom borderless window will not be brought back to the topmost when I click on the parent window. I have to use <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>tab</kbd> to switch to the child window manually.

Is it possible to make my borderless window act like a normal modal window?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue. Each time I click on the parent window, the border-less dialog window comes on top of the parent window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try setting the Topmost property on the window?

```
var myWindow = new MyBorderlessWindow();
myWindow.Owner = this;
myWindow.Topmost = true;
myWindow.ShowDialog();
```